# How to create heatmap with reverse color legend in r?

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap, pheatmap

I would like to generate a heatmap in r(e.g using pheatmap package or other packages), where the smaller the value is, the darker the color is. Use only one color, with light and dark.

```
Example code：
X = matrix(runif(1000,0,1),100,10)
rownames(X) = paste("Var", 1:100, sep = "")
colnames(X) = paste("Var", 1:10, sep = "")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the Blues palette from `RColorBrewer` which could be from dark blue to light blue in `pheatmap` like this:

```r
X = matrix(runif(1000,0,1),100,10)
rownames(X) = paste("Var", 1:100, sep = "")
colnames(X) = paste("Var", 1:10, sep = "")
library(pheatmap)
library(RColorBrewer)
pheatmap(X, color = rev(brewer.pal(9, "Blues")))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-02-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

As @DaveArmstrong mentioned in the comments, you could use a `colorRampPalette` to make it look more continuous like this:

```r
library(pheatmap)
library(RColorBrewer)
pheatmap(X, color=colorRampPalette(rev(brewer.pal(9, "Blues")))(100))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-02-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Or, if you want a color ramp that looks more continuous, use `color=colorRampPalette(rev(brewer.pal(9, "Blues")))(100)`.